# Проблема с установкой Линукс федора

Tags: linux, fedora

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всем привет, есть проблема сейчас ставлю linux fedora 31 и уже примерно 20 минут висит на 2% что делать?

Comment: Ждать..........

Comment: В такой формулировке вопрос не описывает конктерную проблему. Тут только ответ как @Эникейщик написал. Я за 20 минут Fedora установливаю и настраиваю практически полностью как мне надо. Какое железо у ПК? Установка на голое железо, рядом с другой ОС или вируальную машину? Как загрузочный образ создавался? Ну и т.д.